# How to link two checklistbox items?

Tags: c#

I'm using checklistboxes to display the FieldNames associated with a table (another checklistbox ). Multiple checklistboxes are generated dynamically and on checking any of the items from this fires an event 'OnCheckListBoxItemCheck' . Here the current item checked is obtained from the object 'sender'. The doubt is, how can i associate the item checked from the dynamic checklistbox and the item checked from the clbtables? Please Help...

```
 private void clbTables_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {

        int indexofselectedtable;
        indexofselectedtable = Convert.ToInt32(clbTables.SelectedIndex);
        Metadata metadataobj = new Metadata(dbProperties);
        List<string> ColumnNames = new List<string>();
        ColumnNames = metadataobj.GetColumns(clbTables.Items[indexofselectedtable].ToString());
        chklistcolumns = new CheckedListBox();

      //Adds to the Checked ListBox
        for (int j = 0; j < ColumnNames.Count; j++)
        {

            chklistcolumns.Items.Add(ColumnNames.ElementAt(j).ToString());
        }

        this.Controls.Add(chklistcolumns);
        //To fire event for a dynamically generated column checklistboxes
        chklistcolumns.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(OnCheckListBoxItemCheck);
    }
 private void OnCheckListBoxItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs args)
    {
            Columns columnobj = new Columns();
            columnobj.ColumnName = this.chklistcolumns.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
            columnobj.TableName = this.clbTables.SelectedItem.ToString();
            selectedColumnsList.Add(columnobj);

    }
```

Comment: And what happens when multiple checkboxes in one list are checked?

Comment: Works fine for multiple checkboxes in one list as i'm using this.chklistcolumns ...How to recognize the columnname of the object that fires the event? I renames the chklistcolumns with the selecteditem of a table. Is there a way to get that from the object sender?

Comment: `Control cnt = ((CheckBox)sender).Parent` ?

Comment: @achilleterzo ((CheckBox)sender).Parent returning the Form name. My 'sender' object is an item from the CheckedListBox.

Comment: I did not understand your question. What exactly are you trying to do and which part of it does not work? In the long piece of code that you posted, please show where exactly the problem lies, and maybe even write some pseudo-code to show what you would like it to do.

Comment: From the above code I'm naming dynamically generated checkedlistboxes with the checkeditem of clbTables. On checking any of the items(i.e. the column names) from the dynamic chklistcolumns,an itemcheckevent is fired an within this i need to get the name of the chklistcolumns.

            Control parentTable = ((CheckedListBox)sender).Parent; is returning only the Form Name... and  this.chklistcolumns.Name;  returns the name of the checkedlistbox object created recently not the one that fired the event.

Comment: @NewBie is strange, if the checkbox is part of another element, it must return his parent element, i tested it and returned "System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel" type as his parent.

Comment: @achilleterzo  As i'm not using any panel, its returning the Form name not the checkedlistbox name. How can that be returned?

Comment: Oh, maybe i'm starting to understand your request... the sender is the checkedListBox, you let adding the checkbox using .add("item");
checkedLIstBox.parent then is the form... My solution under...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe what you want?

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add("test");
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(checkedListBox1_ItemCheck);

....

void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((CheckedListBox)sender).Name + " is the father of item nr: " + e.Index);
    Console.WriteLine("The value of element nr " + e.Index + " is " + ((CheckedListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString());
}
```